# Why hidden input is affecting my layout? LF Explanation

Tags: php, html, css, input

I needed to use an hidden input to transfer some IDs to the page for each block.. whatever.

I have the following code :

```
<div id="shipping_box" class="formSep well">
    <div id="default_shipping_box" class="shipping_box row-fluid">
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="tracking_id" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code work well and the result is what I expected.

If I do this :

```
<div id="shipping_box" class="formSep well">
    <div id="default_shipping_box" class="shipping_box row-fluid">
        <input type="hidden" name="tracking_id" value="" />
        <div class="span1">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The layout is not respected. See this picture for the demostration :

[image]

Can someone explain why to me ? Hidden input aren't suppose to be "hidden" so they shouldn't affect the layout ?

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/t9M3C/

Near line 285

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows this in action?

Comment: @JoshMein I wanted to but I don't know how to keep my layout and stuff... ? That why I uploaded a picture.

Comment: Are you sure that that is all you are changing? It "shouldn't" make a difference. What browser are you viewing it in? Have you tried a different browser to see if it has the same effect?

Comment: @Gravitate Yes, I am sure. I can recreate the error just by moving the input... Google Chrome last version 21.0.1180.77 m.

Comment: @DavidBélanger If you include your css in the fiddle, you should have no problem recreating the issue, and maybe in the process you will find your real issue.

Comment: In the first example the input is nested inside `.span1` and the second it is not and the div `.span1` is left empty.  Empty tags can sometimes cause weird things to happen.  Without seeing some css and the surrounding html it is hard to say. you using?

Comment: Ok, play with http://jsfiddle.net/t9M3C/. Move the hidden input near line 285 to the div above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is because you have a css rule (in bootstrap.min.css file) that match the firs-child element (but only if has a class*="span") inside the default_shipping_box div.

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
margin-left: 0;
}
```

So, if you put your **hidden input** inside the **div#default_shipping_box** and before the first span, then that rule is not styling the **div.span1** and thats why your template is been afected.

You can fixed adding a simple css rule to the same file...

```
.row-fluid .span1{margin-left:0 !important;}
```

The important, is because you have more files who overite this rule (ex. in bootstrap-responsive.min.css)

Good luck, and i hope it helps
cheers,
Gmo.-

EDIT:
Too slow XD.
Answered while writing ... I agree with the reason explained above.

Comment: yeah, I've seen .. and I edited mine, while you were editing to put that had already been answered. XDXD; Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Using Google Chrome's Inspest Plugin, when you move the input this class:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
     margin-left: 0;
}
```

Gets removed.

This is because in this:

```
<div id="shipping_box" class="formSep well">
    <div id="default_shipping_box" class="shipping_box row-fluid">
        <input type="hidden" name="tracking_id" value="" />
        <div class="span1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This : `<div class="span1">` is not the first child, this: `<input type="hidden" name="tracking_id" value="" />` is.

and in your CSS this is that default class for `[class*="span"]` is:

```
[class*="span"] {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

So use this for example :

```
.row-fluid .span1 {
    margin-left:0 !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap has some CSS that will set the `left-margin` of the first of the child to 0, if the class contains `span`:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
```

When the hidden input is put above the first `span` div, the above `margin-left: 0;` property will not be applied.

The following image shows that when the hidden input is **before**, then the first `span` class has a left-margin.

[image: Hidden input above DIV]

This shows that when the hidden input is **after** the div, that there is no left-margin.

[image: Hidden below above DIV]

EDIT: I seem to have a been beaten twice, while I was getting the screenshots to illustrate the difference!